# Laravel & MySQL schema for menu management

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, eloquent, schema

im building Laravel app which should have menu management, and i’m trying to find best schema for storing menu items & menu types.

The problem App consist of several modules eg.:

```
blog
users
shop
```

Each module can have different views (pages) eg.:

```
blog = list of posts in category, specific post page, search page
users = login page, user profile
shop = list of products in category, product detail, cart, checkout
```

What im trying to achieve is to have within app admin ability to manage menu items such as:

```
1 - create new item

2 - choose item type [blog, user, shop]

3 - choose page [eg. if prev selection is blog i can choose from: list of posts in category, specific post page, search page]

4 - select necessary page attributes [eg. if prev. selector was specified post page, then i have to choose particular post from blog]
```

I don't know what’s the best way to store such data within MySQL. I was thinking about having menu items table and morphing them to particular item types, then morphing menu item types to particular pages but it seems like i will have to create lots of tables. Do you guys have better idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an product issue rather than a technical issue. 
In my opinion you should map all your menu structure first, create a flowchart with all the possible sequences. And finally you be able to choose how you gonna create this. If it never gonna change it could be based in controller actions or, if you decide to change it in more granular way you can set a database model to relate it to your other modules...